# Can you set a minimum cache time for Apache HTTP client?

Tags: java, caching, httpclient, cache-control

We're using the Apache [CachingHttpClientBuilder](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.5.2/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CachingHttpClientBuilder.html).  This will automatically obey Cache-Control headers, which is usually fine, but we have some responses which either don't have a Cache-Control header or specify `no-store`.  Can we override the default behavior on these responses and tell the client to always cache responses for at least X seconds even if the Cache-Control header says `no-store`?

Answer (score 0):

The [CacheConfig](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.5.2/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CacheConfig.html) class allows you to set a mode called "Heuristic Caching."

> Per RFC2616, a cache may cache certain cache entries even if no explicit cache control headers are set by the origin. This behavior is off by default, but you may want to turn this on if you are working with an origin that doesn't set proper headers but where you still want to cache the responses. You will want to [enable heuristic caching](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.5.2/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CacheConfig.html#setHeuristicCachingEnabled(boolean)), then specify either a [default freshness lifetime](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.5.2/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CacheConfig.html#getHeuristicDefaultLifetime()) and/or [a fraction of the time since the resource was last modified](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.5.2/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CacheConfig.html#setHeuristicCoefficient(float)). See Sections 13.2.2 and 13.2.4 of the HTTP/1.1 RFC for more details on heuristic caching.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to use this?  Maybe with an example?  I don't really understand what heuristic caching means.

Comment: The links are to the Oracle documentation for CacheConfig.  CacheConfig is what you provide to the CachingHttpClientBuilder to configure it.  Use the setHeuristicCachingEnabled() method to turn on heuristic caching.  Use  setHeuristicCoefficient() to specify a fraction of time since the resource was last modified.  I presume that will cause CachingHttpClientBuilder to cache the resource during that amount of time.